# Java Overriding Protected Setters and Eliminate Public Setters

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Person Class:

```
public class Person {


    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstname,String lastname) throws InvalidDataException
    {
        setFirstname( firstname);
        setLastname(lastname);
    }


    public void personFirstName(String firstName) throws InvalidDataException { 
        setFirstname(firstName);
    }

    public void personLastName(String lastname) throws InvalidDataException {

        setLastname(lastname);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getlasttName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    protected final void setFirstname(String firstname) throws InvalidDataException{
         if( firstname == null ||firstname.length() < 1) {
                throw new InvalidDataException("First Name Cannot be Empty");
         }
          this.firstName=firstname; 

    }

    protected final void setLastname(String lastname) throws InvalidDataException {

         if( lastname == null ||lastname.length() < 1) {
                throw new InvalidDataException("Last Name Cannot be Empty");

         }

         this.lastName = lastname;
    }



}
```

Professor Class:

```
public class Professor extends Person {


    private String  professorID;



    public Professor(String professorID,String firstname, String lastname) throws InvalidDataException {
        super(firstname, lastname);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setProfessorID(professorID);
    }

    public void setID(String professorID) throws InvalidDataException{

        setProfessorID(professorID);
    }

    public String getID()
    {
        return this.professorID;
    }

    private void setProfessorID(String ID) throws InvalidDataException{
         if( ID == null ||ID.length() < 1) {
                throw new InvalidDataException("ID Cannot be Empty");
         }
          this.professorID=ID; 

    }

    public void printData()
    {
         System.out.println("Professor ID: " + this.getID() + " First Name: " + this.getFirstName() + " Last Name: " + this.getlasttName());
    }

}
```

I've done some research on implementing setters and calling them in my sub-class. By declaring them protected and final, I prevent the sub-class from overriding it and doing unwanted behavior. My question is this, can I now get rid of **personFirstName()** and **personLastName()**? My constructor doesn't use it, and they call the protected final **setFirstname**, and **setLastname()**. Would getting rid of the **public setters** cause an issue later on in development?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Would you suggest removing setFirstName()? My question is, would it pose a problem later on if I do?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I've read elsewhere that it's not desirable to do so. Because I was calling the setters in my constructors, and I read it's not recommended to call constructors with methods that can be overridden.

Comment: Ah, okay, so the point is to avoid calling potentially-overridden methods from the constructor. I can see that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said your goal is to avoid calling methods in the constructor that may be overridden by a subclass. If so, I'd approach it like this:

```
public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.privateSetFirstName(firstName);
    this.privateSetLastName(lastName);
}
private void privateSetFirstName(String firstName) {
    // ...your logic for setting the field...
}
private void privateSetLastName(String lastName) {
    // ...your logic for setting the field...
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.privateSetFirstName(firstName);
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.privateSetLastName(lastName);
}
```

E.g., make the standard setters standard, and keep your implementation-specific details in private methods within your implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I was following the advice given here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410338/most-appropriate-place-for-bounds-checking-constructor-or-setter/12410420#12410420.

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield: Yeah, as soon as you said, I got it. :-)

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder - If I wanted to share the private methods with my subclass, I could declare them protected and final, correct (Like I did in my example above)?

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield: Sure, but my instinct would be not to. They're implementation detail within your class. The only correct way for a subclass to set those fields should be through the base constructor and `setFirstName`/`setLastName`.

Comment: Much appreciated. One more question, the way I implemented it my example, it wouldn't be the desired way of doing it? or it's just too messy?

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield: The only real change with the above is that the standard setters remain standard setters.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid doing stuff within the getters and setter, it can give you a hard time tracking down errors - check the data elsewhere. I think this much simpler version will do:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person() {} // introducing an empty constructor gives you more flexibility


    public Person(String firstname, String lastname) {
        setFirstname( firstname);
        setLastname(lastname);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    } 

    public String getLasttName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

public class Professor extends Person {

    private String  professorID;

    public Professor (super();) {} // introducing an empty constructor gives you more flexibility

    public Professor (String firstname, String lastname, String professorID) {
        super(firstname, lastname);
        this.professorID = professorID;
    }

    public void setID(String professorID) {
        setProfessorID(professorID);
    }

    public String getID() {
        return this.professorID;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm accustomed to doing it the way you've shown. However, when I posted my code other times before I was instructed not to write it that way. Also, implementing an no argument constructor means impartial objects can be created.

Comment: *"You should try to avoid doing stuff within the getters and setter..."* Basic checks in setters are perfectly normal and appropriate.

Comment: In some cases, like in a hibernate entity, having an empty constructor is even mandatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935826/why-does-hibernate-require-no-argument-constructor .

Comment: @Journeycorner: Whether to implement a zero-args constructor is entirely a case-by-case basis. Yes, you need them for certain entity frameworks. That doesn't mean you should always write them. Objects with state should never have invalid state; if args in the constructor are necessary to prevent invalid state, then args in the constructor are necessary. If a framework requires you to have potentially-invalid objects by requiring zero-args constructors, you just bow to the implementation necessity and contain the damage as best you can.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I agree, we don't know the context so there is no silver bullet. However it looks like his classes represent some kind of model, and I would be really surprised to encounter a model that throws an exception after calling a getter.

Comment: @Journeycorner: I don't see any exceptions thrown in getters in the OP's code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Sorry, I meant setter: " public void setID(String professorID) throws InvalidDataException{". Yes, it's not useless but not very common either.

Comment: @Journeycorner: Exceptions from setters are not uncommon.